# Finding a rescource id

Tags: android

In a project I'm working on I try to load a 'texture' to a tile. The 'texture' is nothing more then a *.png file in my Res folder. The information telling me to link the image and the tile together comes from a SQLite database. The problem there is that I get this info as a string (Rock.png for example). How do I get from this string to a resource id (@drawable/rock)?

My first guess was writing a class with a giant case switch where I linked them together, but then I came to the conclusion that that would be rather static (if not completely retarded). So there must be a better way, but until now I've been unable to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the resource Id by doing this

```
int resourceID = MainActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable",
                     MainActivity.this.getPackageName());
```

where

**MainActivity**==> Your current activity
**img** ==> view/drawable name without extension e.g. (.png) and R.(id/string/color....)
**drawable**==> type of your "img"
**MainActivity.this.getPackageName()** ==> current package name